# GtkImage File Name

Tags: gtk

How can I get the file name of the image used in a GtkImage widget?

I have a GtkImage widget that displays different images. I want to be able to click on the GtkImage, determine which image has been clicked i.e. get the file name, then display a larger version.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the value of [`"file"`](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/2.24/GtkImage.html#GtkImage--file) property of `GtkImage` using [`g_object_get_property`](http://developer.gnome.org/gobject/unstable/gobject-The-Base-Object-Type.html#g-object-get-property). Something on these lines:

```
GValue value = {0,}; 
/* If you have glib version 2.30 or higher use:
* GValue value = G_VALUE_INIT;
*/
g_value_init (&value, G_TYPE_STRING);
/* Assuming image is a valid GtkImage */
g_object_get_property(G_OBJECT(image), "file", &value);
printf("\n Filename = %s\n", g_value_get_string(&value));
```

Side note: To make use of the `Glib`'s type system, `g_type_init()` should have been called. `g_type_init()` is called internally as a consequence of Gtk initialization through `gtk_init`.

Hope this helps!