# How do I retrieve the image source file name from a button that has an image?

Tags: c++, gtk3

I'm beginning to learn GTK3 and have hit a roadblock.
I declared an array of buttons Gtk::Button buttons[15], and linked them all to the same onClicked() function. Each button contains a unique image.
When the user clicks a button, I want to retrieve the file name of the image so I know which button was clicked, the images change periodically, so I haven't given them labels.

```
// creating the button array 
for(int i = 0; i < 15; i++){
  Gtk::Image image("nothing.png");
  button[i].signal_clicked().connect(sigc::mem_fun(*this,
    &Window::doOnButtonClicked));
  button[i].set_image(image);
}


//doOnButtonClicked
void Window::doOnButtonClicked(Gtk::Button button){
   onClicked(&button);
}


//the onClicked() code
void onClicked(Gtk::Button * button){
  GValue value = G_VALUE_INIT;
  g_value_init (&value, G_TYPE_STRING);
  g_object_get_property(G_OBJECT(button->get_image()), "file", &value);
  string source = g_value_get_string(&value);
  cout<<source;
 }
```

I did try to follow the steps to [get the file name of the image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8305163/gtkimage-file-name) as listed here, but I realised that I needed to pass my button to extract the Image object, so, I followed the steps in this [to pass in the button object to the function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43187122/how-do-i-connect-a-custom-function-to-the-clicked-action-of-a-gtk-button).

But right now I have the following errors :

> error: return-statement with a value, in function returning 'void' [-fpermissive]
>      { return functor_(); }
>
> no match for call to ‘(sigc::bound_mem_functor1) ()’
>      { return functor_(); }

Thanks for all the help in advance

Comment: Does GTK not allow the identification of controls by an ID? It sounds like the wrong way to do it.

Comment: I'm really new to Gtk, so I don't know what do you mean by that. I can't do button[5], because I don't know which button is being clicked by the user.

Comment: I've resorted to using sigc::bind<Gtk::Button *>(sigc::mem_fun(*this,
    &Window::doOnButtonClicked)), button[i]);   I did realise that I couldn't do this as Gtk::Button, since the copy ctor is deleted.

Comment: I would really appreciate it if someone could let me know if the *this in the sigc::mem_fun(*this, &Window::doOnButtonClicked)); refers to the button that was clicked, and if yes, how do I make use of it.

Comment: Tried playing with GTK years ago and gave it away in favour of WxWidgets as a cross-platform library. In both windows and wx, clicking a specific button causes a particular handler to be called. Hence, you know which control was clicked by whuch callback is invoked. It sounds off, that you'd be told a button was clicked, yet not whuch one... WxWidgets allowwd for the creation of a program that need only be recompiled to run under x64 windows, x64 linux, x32 windows and just for a laugh - a raspberry pi. Sorry i cant help you further.

Comment: Ahhhhhh! Just realized that i glossed over the "and linked them all to the same onClicked() function" part of your initial question.. *that* is the problem. Attach each button to its own handler, simples. :-)

Comment: `sigc::bind<Gtk::Button *>(sigc::mem_fun(*this, &Window::doOnButtonClicked)), button[i]);` is the way to go. You could also use lambda expression. `*this` is the object which doOnButtonClicked wil be called. Since it's a class member passing only doOnButtonClicked is not enough.